# When can a single plane $P$ be constructed through six lines $\ell_n$ in different planes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

In $\mathbb R^3$, consider the reference planes $x = 0, x = 1, y = 0, y = 1, z = 0, z = 1$, and one line in each plane: $\ell_{x=0}, \ell_{x=1}, \ell_{y=0}, \ell_{y=1}, \ell_{z=0}, \ell_{z=1}$.

For which set of $\{\ell_n\}$ is there a plane $P$ that includes all six $l_n$?

---

My *guess* is below, though I've not proven it:

**Conjecture:** There exists such a plane $P$ iff there exist $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb R, \neq 0$ such that the $\ell_n$ include these points:

$$\begin{align*}
\ell_{x=0}:& (0, 0, D/C) \quad (0, D/B, 0)\\
\ell_{x=1}:& (1, 0, (D-A)/C) \quad (1, (D-A)/B, 0)\\
\ell_{y=0}:& (D/A, 0, 0) \quad (0, 0, D/C)\\
\ell_{y=1}:& ((D-B)/A, 1, 0) \quad (0, 1, (D-B)/C)\\
\ell_{z=0}:& (D/A, 0, 0) \quad (0, D/B, 0)\\
\ell_{z=1}:& ((D-C)/A, 0, 1) \quad (0, (D-C)/B, 1).
\end{align*}$$

Furthermore, we can assume $D=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{ \ell_n\}$ as in the OP and assume at least one of the following conditions hold

- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ are coplanar, not parallel and at least one of them is not parallel to a coordinate axys
- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ are parallel, distinct and both of them do not coincide with the $z$-axys
- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ coincide i.e. they coincide with the $z$-axys and $\ell_{z=0}$ is not parallel to a coordinate axys

Than $\{\ell_n\}$ are coplanar lines. If $\{\ell_n\}$ do not satisfy any of the condition than does not exists a plane $P$ containing all six the $\ell_n$-s

---

**Proof**

Two distinct lines on $\mathbb{R}^3$ uniquely determine a plane.

As a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined as the intersection of two not parallel planes and we know that $\ell_n$ is contained in one of the reference planes if $\ell_{x=0}$ does not coincide with $\ell_{y=0}$ and they are coplanar it is enough to find the plane identified by this two lines and impose that such plane is not parallel to any of the reference planes.

So let $\ell_{x=0}$ an arbitrary line with direction $(0,a_1,b_1)$ and passing throught the point $P_{x=0}=(0,y_1,z_1)$ and similarly $\ell_{y=0}$ has direction $(a_2,0,b_2)$ and goes throught the point $P_{y=0}=(x_2,0,z_2)$.

**If $\ell_{x=0}$ is not parallel to $\ell_{y=0}$**

Consider the vector $P_{x=0}-P_{y=0}$ the two lines are coplanar iif the [triple scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) is zero i.e
$$
-x_2a_1 b_2+ y_1 b_1 a_2  - a_1 a_2(z_1-z_2)=0
$$
If this condition is satisfied the equation of the plane containing the two lines is
$$
a_1 b_2 x + b_1 a_2 (y-y_1)-a_1 a_2(z+z_1)=0 
$$
If at least one between $b_1$ and $b_2$ is not zero (i.e. at least one of $\ell_{x=0}$ or $\ell_{y=0}$ is not parallel to a coordinate axys), this plane is not parallel to any of the reference planes and so it characterizes the remaining lines. *e.g.*
$$
\ell_{x=1} : \begin{cases}a_1 b_2 x + b_1 a_2 (y-y_1)-a_1 a_2(z+z_1)=0 \\ x=1 \end{cases}
$$

Otherwise it is parallel to the $z=0$ plane and so it is impossible for the $6$ lines to be coplanar

**If $\ell_{x=0}$ is parallel to $\ell_{y=0}$**

**if they are distinct** the two lines identify the plane
$$
 y_1 (x-x_2)+ x_2 y =0 
$$
If $y_1 \ne 0 \ne x_2$ (i.e. $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ are not the $z$-axys) the plane is not parallel to any of the reference planes and so this characterizes all the remaining lines.  Otherwise the plane is parallel to $x=0$ or $y=0$ and so it is not possible for the $6$ lines to be coplanar

**If they coincide** they coincide with the $z$-axys. Consider now an arbitrary line $\ell_{z=0}$ with direction ratio $(a_3,b_3,0)$. If $(0,0,0) \notin \ell_{z=0}$ the line is not coplanar with the $z$-axys. Otherwise the equation for the plane containing the $z$-axys and $\ell_{z=0}$ is

$$
b_3x - a_3 y=0
$$

If $a_3 \ne 0 \ne b_3 $ (i.e. $\ell_{x=1}$ is not parallel to a coordinate axys) this plane is not parallel to any of the reference planes i.e. it characterizes all the remaining lines *e.g.*
$$
\ell_{x=1} : \begin{cases} b_3 x-  a_3 y=0 \\ x=1\\ \end{cases}
$$

(this disproves your conjecture as it is possible to let $\ell_{x=0}$ be the $z$-axys. Thus $\left(0,\frac{D}{B},0\right) \notin \ell_{x=0}$ unless $D=0$)

Otherwise the plane is parallel to either $y=0$ or $x=0$ and, as before it is impossible that all the lines are coplanar

Comment: I believe that the 6 lines can definitely be coplanar, as demonstrated by the fact that [a plane and cube can intersect in a hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945231/plane-slice-of-a-cube-to-get-a-hexagon).

Comment: @SRobertJames which part of the proof do you think is wrong? The six lines can definitely be coplanar. I think i have characterized any case in which this can happen.
If you are talking of the disproof of the conjecture: i have only disproven the  "only if" part. There are lines that are not in the form you have wriiten that are still coplanar, but the family of lines that you have written can be coplanar

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you are proving.  Perhaps you could state the claim clearly more clearly, then show how you prove it.

Comment: @SRobertJames you asked "for what set of $\{\ell_n\}$ there is a plane $P$ that includes all six $\ell_n$". I have proven that such sets are:
- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ are coplanar, not parallel and at least one of them is not parallel to a coordinate axys

- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ are parallel, distinct and both of them do not coincide with the $z$-axys

- $\ell_{x=0}$ and $\ell_{y=0}$ coincide i.e. they coincide with the $z$-axys and $\ell_{z=0}$ is not parallel to a coordinate axys
and that the remaining lines are uniquely determined