# What are the maximum number of solutions to a system of non-linear inequalities?

Tags: calculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

What are the maximum number of solutions to a system of non-linear inequalities?  In particular:

Let $A, B, C$ be real nonzero numbers.  Consider the set $S = \{\frac 1 A, \frac 1 B, \frac 1 C, \frac {1 -A} B, \frac {1 - B} A, \frac {1 - A } C, \frac {1 -C } A, \frac {1 - B} C, \frac {1 - C} B\}$.

Let $T = \{ s \in S | 0 \leq s \leq 1 \}.$  What is the cardinality of $T$?

I conjecture it can be any of $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, but no greater.

**Motivation:** I believe $\#T$ is the number of vertices formed by [intersections between an (almost) arbitrary plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850230/when-can-a-single-plane-p-be-constructed-through-six-lines-ell-n-in-differe) ($Ax + By + Cz = 1$) and the unit cube.

What is $\#T$? Does it vary if we make the inequality strict?

---

## Update

To address @nickalh's questions: The question intends to ask: Given set $S$, how many elements $s$ of $S$ can satisfy $0 \leq s \leq 1$ (or $0 < s < 1$)?

The question does *not* ask "How many values of $A, B, C$ can result in such an $s$?", which would clearly be infinite, as nickalh points out.

This is analogous to asking "How many intersections can two distinct real algebraic curves of degree 2 have (in the real plane)?" where the answer is "Either 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4".  There are infinite curves and infinite coefficients which result in two intersections, infinite places in the plane where they may intersect, but the maximum number of intersections is 4.

If there is a preferred way to express this question, or better terms to use, I'd appreciate learning them.

Finally, nickalh asks about the tag "calculus".  This is because I attempted to solve this using calculus (by finding extrema or tangents to identify "turning points".)

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but notice that if $\frac 1A\in S$, then we know that $\frac 1A\leq 1$ which means $A\geq 1$, meaning that $\frac{1-A}{B}$ can only be in $T$ if $A=1$. So that already limits the size of $T$ considerably.

Comment: @5xum Counterexample $A=2,B=-2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Good point, I misread "nonzero" as "nonnegative" :(

Comment: The solution to most systems of linear inequalities over real numbers are intervals in 1 dimension, areas in $\Bbb{R}^2$ or shapes in 3 variables $\Bbb{R}^3$.  All of these have infinite cardinality due to intersections of the real numbers.  Perhaps you mean vertices?

Please define #T more clearly in the context of your specific question.
What am I missing?

Why the calculus tag?  What does this exercise have to do with Calculus?

Comment: @nickalh Updated - please let me know if that clarifies.

Comment: I figured there was something obvious one of was missing.  Looks like it was me.  LOL.